# The File is damaged and cannot be repaired

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".pdf"; 
    Response.ClearContent(); 
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "7pt");
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("color", "Black");
    Panel_Name.RenderControl(htextw);// .RenderControl(htextw);
    //Name of the Panel 
    Document document = new Document();
    document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 15, 5);
    FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 50, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLUE);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();
    StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
    HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlworker.Parse(str);
    document.Close();
    Response.Write(document);
```

I have return this code to generate pdf of an aspx page(i.e. Default.aspx to Default.pdf). It generates a pdf file but the pdf file generated is not supported I have the latest version of pdf. It gives an error of opening the document. The File is damaged and cannot be repaired.

Comment: I have return this code to generate pdf of an aspx page(i.e. Default.aspx to Default.pdf).It generates an pdf file but the pdf file generated is not supported I have an latest version of pdf.It gives an error of opening the document.The File is damaged and cannot be repaired.

Comment: Also, another error is with the document.Close();-> where it says that it is unable to get path.I am really stuck with this.I need help so please can anyone advise something.Thanks in advance.

Comment: the library  ITextSharp provides the facility to convert aspx to  PDS, as well as other facilities too, please go through my post it will help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download [ITextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and add its reference to your project. [ITextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is a free HTML to PDF Library. You can download it using the following download link.

> **HTML Markup**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <img src = "//www.aspsnippets.com/images/Blue/Logo.png" /><br />
    </div>
    <div style = "font-family:Arial">This is a test page</div>
    <div>
       <table border = "1" width = "100">
          <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>
          <tr><td>John</td><td>11</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Sam</td><td>13</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Tony</td><td>12</td></tr>
       </table>
    </div>
    <div>
       <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" onclick="btnExport_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

> **Namespaces**

```
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

> **C# Code**

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Basically  its my very old question,  which wqs resolved  already  byt seems like your answer also correct. There is one another library named syncfusion which provides many more facility rather than iTextSharp. But its in cost.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the third party library to create pdf such as [PDFizer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfizer/)

Comment: I have download now please will you guide me how to use.I have already done it using ItextSharp.dll but its not working.

Comment: Pdfizer is based on iTextSharp as well. It works but the free version doesnt support the CSS and backgroupd image. If you want to have good tools I suggest you ABCPdf. Im using ABCPdf and so happy with that. http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-9.htm

Comment: Doc theDoc = new Doc();
    theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("htmlimport.pdf"));
    theDoc.Clear();              when i use above code it gives me an error like The type or namespace name  doc could not be found can u please tell why this error come?